# Row Count outputting - in front of the number of rows in table

Tags: php

Good day,

i have the following code in php

```
$sellast2 = "SELECT id, staffid, password FROM staff WHERE staffid=$staffid";
$result4 = $pdo->prepare($sellast2);
$result4->execute(); 
$rowcount = $result4->rowCount();
echo $rowcount;
```

I am expecting that the row count would be one since this table only has one record in it.

The variable is outputting -1 and not 1 as expected. 
What does the minus mean and why does it output a minus?

I am using Microsoft sql server management studio as the database.

Answer (score 0):

$sellast2 = "SELECT id, staffid, password FROM staff WHERE staffid='$staffid'";

use your $staffid in single quotes like i did, then pass a valid staff id and get your result

Comment: still having the same problem. I still see a minus sign at the front of the 1